# Alinhar elementos ion-navbar - Ionic

Tags: ionic, ionic3

Olá, quero fazer o alinhamento de 3 elementos (IONIC) dentro de uma ion-navbar porém não sei como posicionar os elementos corretamente, alguém poderia me auxiliar? Abaixo segue o trecho do código juntamente com a imagem, eu quero colocar um elemento na frente do outro, ou seja, primeiro o botão toggle, seguido pela barra de consulta e por fim o botão do carrinho de compras.

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>


      <button ion-button menuToggle >
          <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
      </button>

    <ion-searchbar
      [(ngModel)]="descricao"
      (ionInput)="showVitrine()"
      (ionCancel)="showVitrine()">
    </ion-searchbar> 

    <button ion-fab mini end><ion-icon name="ios-cart-outline"></ion-icon></button>

  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

faltou colocar a a tag de ion-buttons end:

```
 <ion-navbar>


    <button ion-button menuToggle >
        <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>

  <ion-searchbar
    [(ngModel)]="descricao"
    (ionInput)="showVitrine()"
    (ionCancel)="showVitrine()">
  </ion-searchbar> 

  <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-fab mini end><ion-icon name="ios-cart-outline"></ion-icon></button>
    </ion-buttons>


</ion-navbar>
```

Comment: Muito bom Felipe, Deu certo. Obrigado.